# Determine if Full Keyboard Access is enabled

Tags: ios, uiaccessibility

I'm looking for a way to determine if Accessibility's `Full Keyboard Access` is enabled on iOS.  I'm not seeing anything in UIAccessibility, along the lines of `UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool HasHardwareKeyboard => GCKeyboard.CoalescedKeyboard != null;
```

Comment: This tells us if there's a hardware keyboard connected to the device, not if Full Keyboard Access is enabled.  Full Keyboard Access is an accessibility feature that allows a user who has difficulty touching an iOS device screen to instead control the device using a physical keyboard.  https://www.cultofmac.com/688501/ipados-134-full-keyboard-access-offers-incredible-touch-free-control/ has a nice summary.